# How To Iterate Over Members of a Structure Array in VB.net Using Member Function

Tags: vb.net, iteration, structure

I have a vb.net enumeration that looks like this:

```
' define enumeration for keypad states
Enum KeyPadState
    KEYPAD_NO           ' no keypad
    KEYPAD_UC           ' upper case keypad
    KEYPAD_LC           ' lower case keypad
    KEYPAD_NU           ' numeric keypad
    KEYPAD_SY           ' symbol keypad
End Enum
```

I then defined a structure element to be used to translate the members of the above enumeration from enumeration values to string values and back again. The declared structure looks like below. Note the member functions that I have tried to insert. The "New" one is working.

```
' define keypad type look up structure
Private Structure KeyPadXlat
    Dim KeyPadEnum As KeyPadState
    Dim KeyPadStr As String

    ' initializer subroutine
    Public Sub New(nKeyPadEnum As KeyPadState, nKeyPadStr As String)
        KeyPadEnum = nKeyPadEnum
        KeyPadStr = nKeyPadStr
    End Sub

    ' translate string to enum
    Public Function ToEnum(xKeyPadStr As String) As KeyPadState

        For Each item As KeyPadXlat In ????

        Next
    End Function

    ' translate enum to string
    Public Function ToStr(xKeyPadEnum As KeyPadState) As String

    End Function

End Structure
```

The actual instance of the structure array is shown below with its initializer code.

```
Dim KeyPadLookUp() As KeyPadXlat = { _
                                    New KeyPadXlat(KeyPadState.KEYPAD_NO, "KEYPAD_NO"), _
                                    New KeyPadXlat(KeyPadState.KEYPAD_UC, "KEYPAD_UC"), _
                                    New KeyPadXlat(KeyPadState.KEYPAD_LC, "KEYPAD_LC"), _
                                    New KeyPadXlat(KeyPadState.KEYPAD_NU, "KEYPAD_NU"), _
                                    New KeyPadXlat(KeyPadState.KEYPAD_SY, "KEYPAD_SY") _
                                    }
```

So my question is with regard to the member functions I am trying to create to translate back and forth between the enumeration value and the string value. I have copied one of them here again for reference:

```
    ' translate string to enum
    Public Function ToEnum(xKeyPadStr As String) As KeyPadState

        For Each item As KeyPadXlat In ????

        Next
    End Function
```

What I need help with is how to write the code for the For Each loop so that it iterates across all of the elements of the structure array when being in a member function.

Comment: You don't need any loops.  The `Enum` class already has everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you really don't need all that code. This should do it nicely.

```
    Enum KeyPadState
    KEYPAD_NO           ' no keypad
    KEYPAD_UC           ' upper case keypad
    KEYPAD_LC           ' lower case keypad
    KEYPAD_NU           ' numeric keypad
    KEYPAD_SY           ' symbol keypad
End Enum

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim state As KeyPadState
    state = KeyPadState.KEYPAD_LC

    'this line will assign the name of the enum `state` to a string called `tempstring`
    'It's hardly worth encapsulating it into a function so I've left it as is
    'But if you want to provide consistent code, it would be better to.
    Dim tempstring As String
    tempstring = [Enum].GetName(GetType(KeyPadState), state)

    Dim anyString As String = "KEYPAD_UC"
    Dim tempState As KeyPadState
    'the following line will try to parse `anyString` to an enum value of the same type as the variable to be assigned.
    'In this case `state`
    tempState = ParseToKeypadState(anyString)

End Sub

Private Function ParseToKeypadState(tempString As String) As KeyPadState
    Dim returnValue As KeyPadState
    If Not [Enum].TryParse(tempString, returnValue) Then
        'handle parsing error here
    End If
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind and helpful reply.

Answer (score 0):

There's all sorts wrong with your code there.

Firstly, I'd suggest that your naming conventions are poor.  If you do as is done throughout the .NET Framework then you enumeration would look like this:

```
Enum KeyPadState
    None
    UpperCase
    LowerCase
    Numeric
    Symbol
End Enum
```

That's clear and self-documenting.

Secondly, it is not recommended to use abbreviations like "Xlat".  That's meaningless to anyone without prior knowledge.  Is it so onerous to write "Translate" and then let Intellisense find it whenever you need to use it in code?

As for the implementation of your class, why does it need any methods at all?  You are passing in the `KeyPadState` value and the text representation when you create an instance so what is there for those methods to do?  Your structure should simply be a constructor and two properties:

```
Private Structure KeyPadStateTranslation

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As KeyPadState
    Public ReadOnly Property Text As String

    Public Sub New(value As KeyPadState, text As String)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub

End Structure
```

The property values are set when the instance is created and they are retrieved via the properties.  Everything also has an appropriate name.

That said, you don't even need to provide the text because you can simply call `ToString` on the value to get it:

```
Private Structure KeyPadStateTranslation

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As KeyPadState
    Public ReadOnly Property Text As String

    Public Sub New(value As KeyPadState)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.Text = value.ToString()
    End Sub

End Structure
```

Also, the fact that that structure is declared `Private` is an issue.  That indicates that it is declared inside another type.  That's not right.  Structures are first-class types, just like classes, so they belong in their own dedicated code file, just like classes.

What's the point of that structure at all though?  You'd still have to loop through your array to find an instance that matches either a value or some text so it doesn't really help.  A `Dictionary` might be better but you may as well just call `ToString` on a value if you need to convert that way and use `Enum.Parse` or `.TryParse` when you need to go the other way.